# List of protected nested class

Tags: java

I have a Java class with a nested protected class in it. In a method of another class (and in another package) I have to make a list of such nested protected type.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

```
// SomeClass.java
package stuff;

public class SomeClass {
  protected class Nested {
    int x;
    public Nested setX(int arg) {
      x = x;
      return this;
    }
    public int getX() {
      return x;
    }
  }

  public Nested make(int x) {
    return new Nested().setX(x);
  }
}
```

```
// MyClass.java
package project;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import stuff.SomeClass;

public class MyClass {
  public SomeClass instance;

  // I don't know what I should insert ...
  public List< /* ... here... */ ?> method() {
    var list = new ArrayList< /* ... and here... */ >();
    list.add(instance.make(1));
    list.add(instance.make(2));
    return list; // ... to return an ArrayList<SomeClass.Nested>
  }
}
```

Maybe something like the C++ `decltype()` or some kind of template deduction whould work!

Even some reflection magic would be ok for me.

PS.
I whuld not modify SomeClass

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a public interface which `Nested` implements. Then you can refer to that interface type `List<MyInterface>`, for example. And `make()` returns the interface type, instead of `Nested`. This is the pattern used by many classes in the standard Java API.

Comment: SomeClass and SomeClass.Nested are not my stuff, I can't touch them.

Comment: @asdru And `SomeClass.make()` returns `SomeClass.Nested`, not some interface that `SomeClass.Nested` implements?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, as `Nested` is not accessible outside of `SomeClass`. You can either make `Nested` public (or package-private if both `SomeClass` and `MyClass` are in the same package), or move `MyClass` inside of `SomeClass`.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid touching `SomeClass`?

Comment: @asdru Nope. A protected class is not visible outside that class. So you either have to change `SomeClass` to do what you want or try to find a different solution.

Comment: @asdru I told a small fib here. Technically, `protected` members are available in the current class, in other classes in the same package, and in subclasses (whether in the same package or not). So one solution is to `extend SomeClass`. Then you can access `Nested `inside your new child class. Alternatively, you can declare a class in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know, that ther're `static` and `not static` inner classes.

Only one differenct: `static` class does not have a reference to it's parent class (but `non static` does). So it is not possible to create `non static` inner class without it's parent.

In case you want to have a list (e.g. `Tree` and `Tree.Node`), looks like you should create a `static inner class`.

Anyway, you can create a list of inner classes like `List<[ParentClass].[InnerClass]>` (you can have many `.` like `List<A.B.C.D.E>`).

```java
public class MyClass {
  public SomeClass instance;

  public List<SomeClass.Nested> method() {
    List<SomeClass.Nested> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(instance.make(1));
    list.add(instance.make(2));
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: in this example jdoodle.com/ia/zRI the compiler says "./project/MyClass.java:12: error: SomeClass.Nested has private access in SomeClass"